# Where are fixtures located in the file structure of synpress (cypress) tests?

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing, fixtures, metamask

I am attempting to test my react app using synpress, which is a wrapper around cypress that allows you to interact with the metamask crypto wallet browser extension. I have set up my tests and they are working, but I need to utilize a fixture for some of them, but I cannot figure out where the fixtures are stored.

https://github.com/synthetixio/synpress#readme

Below is the current folder setup I have (which is the same as how the docs are):

```
project_dir
└── src
└── tests
    └── e2e
        └── .eslintrc.js
        └── tsconfig.json
        └── specs
            └── example-spec.js
        └── pages
            └── example-page.js
```

I need to read in some data from a fixture, so I have added a fixtures folder to the e2e directory (such that it is at `project_dir/tests/e2e/fixtures`), but no matter what I try it is erroring and saying that fixtures should be stored under `node_modules@synthetixio/synpress/fixtures/`, which I don't think would be correct.

Is there additional config required to utilise fixtures?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the example `package.json` scripts [here](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress/blob/90cafd68218434081a1c7a22c9577084bfba9fc7/package.json#L43), you can specify the fixtures folder on the command line

```js
"test:e2e": "start-server-and-test ... --config='fixturesFolder=tests/e2e/fixtures'"
```

Or try adding `synpress.json` to project root - [synpress.json](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress/blob/dev/synpress.json)

```js
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
    "userAgent": "synpress",
    "retries": { "runMode": 0, "openMode": 0 },
    "integrationFolder": "tests/e2e/specs",

    "fixturesFolder": "tests/e2e/fixtures",

    "screenshotsFolder": "tests/e2e/screenshots",
    "videosFolder": "tests/e2e/videos",
    "chromeWebSecurity": true,
    "viewportWidth": 1366,
    "viewportHeight": 768,
    "component": {
        "componentFolder": ".",
        "testFiles": "**/*spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    },
    "env": {
        "coverage": false
    },
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 30000,
    "requestTimeout": 30000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load an image into an input file just do it this way, this saved me a lot of time.

```
cy.get('input[type="file"]', { force: true }).selectFile({
    contents: 'filePath',
    fileName: 'fileName',
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
}, { force: true });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the fixture folder path in config.js file

```
{
 "fixturesFolder": "/tests/e2e/fixtures"
}
```

You can also verify the fixture folder value in Cypress Test Runner.

1. Open Cypress Test runner: *npx cypress open*
2. Settings
3. Find Fixture Folder

[image]